# Trigger event on multiple features when hovering over any of those in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, hover, polyline, polyline-decorator

I have a layer with two polylines and polylineDecorators. I would like to highlight both polylines and polylineDecorators when I hover on any of these. Right now I'm able to highlight only one at the time when hovering on it.
Here is my code:

```
var layer_migration = L.layerGroup({
          layerName: 'layer_migration',
          pane: 'linesPane',
        });

function onEachFeature_migration (feature, layer) { 

     var polyline = L.polyline(layer.getLatLngs(),{
         color: "#8B0000",weight: 5,opacity: 0.4,dashArray: '8,8',
         dashOffset: 0
     }).addTo(layer_migration);
             

     var PLdecorator1 = L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
            patterns: [{
              offset: '104%',
              repeat: 100,
              symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 16,
                      pathOptions: {color: "#8B0000",fillOpacity: 0.6,weight: 0
                }
              })
          }]
     }).addTo(layer_migration)

     var myfeatures = L.featureGroup([polyline,PLdecorator1]).addTo(layer_migration);

     myfeatures.on('mouseover', function(e) {
         var layer = e.target;
             layer.setStyle({color: '#8B0000',opacity: 1,fillOpacity:1
            });
     });

}
```

Any help super appreciated.

Thanks,

P

Answer (score 0):

In your mouseover callback, I think that `e.target` will just refer to the individual layer (polyline or decorator) that triggered the event, not the collection of layers that make up the feature group.  I've not tested it, but according to [the docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#featuregroup), you ought to be able to get the effect you want by calling `.setLayer()` on the feature group itself:

```
 myfeatures.on('mouseover', function(e) {
     myfeatures.setStyle({color: '#8B0000',opacity: 1,fillOpacity:1});
 });
```

Also, if the two polylines are created by two separate calls to `onEachFeature_migration()`, then they will end up as two separate feature groups.  To get around this, you might need to assign an empty `featureGroup` to `myfeatures` outside the function, then add the new polylines to it inside the function using `myfeatures.addLayer()`.

Comment: Hi JRI, thanks for the reply. I tried it, but it doesn't work. It still only highlights the feature I'm hovering on.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address another potential part of the problem. Are you able to post your code as a minimal working example on JSFiddle or similar, to show what's actually going wrong?

Comment: Hi JRI, sorry for disappearing. I will try to upload a working example soon! Thanks for the help!